# mod_rewrite apache for custom flat links gets stuck

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, relative-path

I want to create flat links for my website. The `.htaccess` code is following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z]+)?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
</IfModule>`
```

Now my website is working which can be seen through `print_r($_GET)` and getting all the values.

My website has a code like this: `<img src="images/icons/image.png" />`, where the image resides on path: `/images/icons/up.png`.

Now I can visit my website as: `http://somedomain.com/home` and everything works fine. But when I put: `http://somedomain.com/home/`, it gets stuck.

The image gets a path like this for the browser: `http://somedomain.com/home/images/icons/image.png` which is not available and it should be: `http://somedomain.com/images/icons/image.png`.

How to solve this?

It would helpful if there is any solution by modifying the **.htaccess** as I want to use relative paths for all links and not full path.

---

Thanks to Ben Clifford for your help. According to him if I redirect the second rule one to the format like the first one and not over index.php. Then it should work.

Comment: Include the base-url metatag in your head. See if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change that second rewrite rule to redirect the user to the non-/ version of the path, rather than to index.php; then when that redirected page is loaded it would hit the first rule, with the correct base path.

The issue is that the image name replaces everything after the last / in the URL: when you say somedomain.com/home then the image filename is appended to somedomain.com/ but in the second case, the final / is *after* the home. Using a rewrite rule to prune this / off would fix that, i think.

Comment: Ok, got the point. But it would be helpful if you build that code for the redirection as you stated, as I am a newbie to this mod_rewrite stuff.

Comment: maybe this: RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z]+)/?$ /$1 [R]